Do not start searching before I press "ENTER"
The Windows-10 Windows Search is a hit on the nervous system :-)
I have started, typing File:, and it already started.
Then I typed File:C and it started again.
Then I typed File:Co and it started again.
...
By the time I had type File:Company.Framwork.dll it had started that many times that the performance of the search dropped enormously.
Is there a way to indicate in Windows-10 that the search only should be started after I've finished typing? (E.g. it only starts searching when I press the ENTER button)

I very rarely use it, for this reason. I would use cmd instead.

You have disabled online content, I presume? I cannot replicate the behavior you describe.

Windows Search displays web content by default unless disabled.

@Ramhound: I don't want Windows search to show web content. How can I disable that?

@spikey_richie: the problem with commandline is that I want to have the lastest file and copy it somewhere. Dir /S /B <filename> does not yield last modification date and Dir /S <filename>| findstr /I "<filename>" yields last modification date, but not directory. Hence my choice for Windows Search.

See https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-web-results-windows-10-search or other online sources for disabling web and Bing search resutls.

@DrMoishePippik: I followed that link but I couldn't find the settings, mentioned in the article.

Windows does not natively support an "Enter-to-start-search" option for the built-in search.
My personal solution to this is to use the Freeware third-party search tool Everything, which has an option to allow you to finish typing your query and press Enter before searching.
